# Flysystem/CSV throwing exception when trying to create a new CSV

Tags: csv, flysystem

I am using Flysystem\CSV to create a CSV and I'm running into the following problem with my code:

```
namespace App;

use League\Csv\Writer;

class Example
{
    public function writeToCsv()
    {
        $csv = Writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject);
    }

}
```

As per [this](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/blob/master/examples/writing.php) example.

I've checked that `SplTempFileObject` is being instantiated properly, and it is.

Yet there is an exception being thrown by `AbstractCsv`.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/exampleuser/vendor/league/csv/src/AbstractCsv.php on line 210
```

That line has the following return statement:

```
/**
 * Return a new {@link Writer} instance from a {@link AbstractCsv} object
 *
 * @param string $open_mode the file open mode flag
 *
 * @return Writer
 */
public function newWriter($open_mode = 'r+')
{
    return $this->newInstance(Writer::class, $open_mode);
}
```

I've double-checked that the package is installed correctly and it is.

PHP version `5.4.45`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `::class` name resolution is not available in 5.4. Which has come in with [5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php)